# Xamarin's HttpClient throws Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a simple Xamarin Forms app and have been messing with network functionality.
I have noticed that if I try to fetch a URL of a non-existing server, `Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException` is eventually thrown by HttpClient on Android. It is catchable using `catch(Exception)`, but is it possible to use a more specific catch clause?

Comment: You can catch the `Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException` instead of `Exception`

Comment: @SushiHangover unfortunately, Java.Net.* classes cannot be referenced from user code directly.

Comment: It IS Xamarin.Android code accessible, if you are talking about NetStd2 code, then use a catch `when` expression and test its ToString name.

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, sorry for not clarifying that enough. I indeed need to catch it from a shared library. Thank you for your assistance.